# Bluetooth capable or does this simply imply its Bluetooth capabilities are limited to networking?

Tags: bluetooth

Thanks for your time and assistance! :)

The following statement is part of the description for a laptop I am considering. Can someone please explain if it is referring only to the networking specs as having Bluetooth capabilities and not generally with respect to the computer? Perhaps if you have Bluetooth networking you simultaneously also then have Bluetooth capabilities with respect to other components of the computer, i.e. file transfer, etc... I'm afraid I don't understand Bluetooth technology enough to distinguish.

"Integrated 802.11 b/g/n Built-in Bluetooth™ V4.0 10/100/1000 Base T"

Answer (score 0):

There are actually 3 separate specs listed in that line:

Integrated 802.11 b/g/n  <-- wireless LAN

Built-in Bluetooth™ V4.0  <-- bluetooth

10/100/1000 Base T  <-- wired LAN

The laptop should have standard bluetooth capabilities.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and especially for taking the time out to answer a stranger's question. I sincerely appreciate it. rainmom4x

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please explain if it is referring only to the networking specs as having Bluetooth capabilities and not generally with respect to the computer?

The whole computer has Bluetooth capabilities.